# Append to array in powershell job

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing, icmp

I was able to find a piece of code that could ping all systems at once, better than any other job examples I've come across. This thing can take an entire file full of hosts, line by line, and ping them all literally at the same time. But how can I add the ones that are up to my `$online` array? I tried adding in the `true` block but it didn't work. Im simply trying to stick `$online += $pc` somewhere. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
$online = @()
$pc = Get-Content C:\servers.txt 
$pc | ForEach-Object { Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Count 1 -AsJob } | Get-Job | Receive-Job -Wait | Select-Object @{Name='ComputerName';Expression={$_.Address}},@{Name='Reachable';Expression={if ($_.StatusCode -eq 0) { $true } else { $false }}} | ft -AutoSize
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue here is the pipe ft -autosize.

Try to pipe after the if/else statement as per below:

```
| ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Reachable -eq $true) {
        $online += $_.ComputerName
    }
}
```

Then if you want to view the results you can always do:

```
$online | ft -AutoSize
```

I'd also suggest a better formatting as all one line isn't easy to read. Try something like this:

```
$online = @()
$pc = Get-Content C:\servers.txt 
$pc | ForEach-Object { 
    Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Count 1 -AsJob 
} | Get-Job | Receive-Job -Wait | 
Select-Object @{Name='ComputerName';Expression={$_.Address}},@{Name='Reachable';Expression={
    if ($_.StatusCode -eq 0) { 
        $true 
    } else { 
        $false 
    }
}} | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Reachable -eq $true) {
        $online += $_.ComputerName
    }
}
$online | ft -AutoSize
```

Comment: this answer was the best because although Santiago's answer did work, `$online` did not exactly contain the hosts unless I did a foreach on it, and in my case I can't utilize it. I needed only the hosts and no formatting within it. Thank you both for the excellent answers!

Answer (score 1):

You can store the result of your jobs and then filter by `Reachable`. I've also simplified your code a bit and added `-AutoRemove` which I consider important to dispose your jobs when done.

```bash
$result = Get-Content C:\servers.txt | ForEach-Object {
    Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Count 1 -AsJob
} | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        ComputerName = $_.Address
        Reachable    = $_.StatusCode -eq 0
    }
}

$online = $result | Where-Object Reachable

# if you want just the `ComputerName` values, you can do
$online = $result | Where-Object Reachable | ForEach-Object ComputerName

# or easier, using member-access enumeration and `.Where` method
$online = $result.Where{ $_.Reachable }.ComputerName
```

If you're interested in grouping the results between Reachable and Not Reachable during enumeration, the way to do it is with a [`hash table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2) having 2 [`List<T>` values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-7.0).

```bash
$result = @{
    Online  = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
    Offline = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
}

Get-Content C:\servers.txt | ForEach-Object {
    Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Count 1 -AsJob
} | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob | ForEach-Object {
    $obj = [pscustomobject]@{
        ComputerName = $_.Address
        Reachable    = $_.StatusCode -eq 0
    }

    if($obj.Reachable) {
        return $result['Online'].Add($obj)
    }
    
    $result['Offline'].Add($obj)
}

$result.Online.ComputerName # => has all reachable records
```

Comment: thanks. that did work. but is there a way to just get the hosts into `$online` without any other information such as `"ComputerName"`, `"Reachable"` and the dashes under that? I add `$online | Select-Object ComputerName` but now just want to get only the hosts in there to do further processing.

Comment: if getting the reachable hosts within the loop without filtering after is what was important to you, you could have mentioned here and I would have shown you how. the answer you've accepted is not the best representation of how it should be done... @unixpipe